# How do I turn a list of lists into separate integer sequences?

Tags: python, list, sequence

So I need to convert a list of lists:

```
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], [2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]]
```

into separate integer sequences:
Sequence # 1

```
1 3 5 7 9 11
```

Sequence # 2

```
2 4 6 8
```

Sequence # 3

```
1 2 3 4 10 20 30 40 50
```

Sequence # 4

```
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
```

in a function.
So far, I have

```
def printIntegerSequences(integerSequences):
    for i in len(integerSequences):
        print("Sequence #", i+1,' '.join(str(e) for e in integerSequences[i]))
```

where integerSequence is the list presented above, but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: len(integerSequences) is not iterable because it is just an integer and integers alone are just numerical values

Comment: `for i in len(integerSequences):` does not make sense. Probably you meant `for i in range(len(integerSequences)):`. But even better would be `for i, seq in enumerate(integerSequences):`. Then you can refer to both `i` (the index) and `seq` (the sequence) rather than to `i` and `integerSequences[i]`.

Comment: @Stef: They could even use `for i, seq in enumerate(integerSequences, 1):` so they don't need to do `i + 1`, in the one place they still use `i`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Indeed. I included your advice in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```py
def printIntegerSequences(integerSequences):
    for i in len(integerSequences):
        print("Sequence #", i+1,' '.join(str(e) for e in integerSequences[i]))
```

should instead be:

```py
def printIntegerSequences(integerSequences):
    for i in range(len(integerSequences)):
        print("Sequence #", i+1,' '.join(str(e) for e in integerSequences[i]))
```

or even better yet:

```py
def printIntegerSequences(integerSequences):
    for i, seq in enumerate(integerSequences, start=1):
        print("Sequence #", i,' '.join(str(e) for e in seq))
```

Relevant documentation:

- [ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range);
- [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate);
- [Tutorial: `for` statements and `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: Or even shorter: `print(f"Sequence #{i+1}: {' '.join(map(str,seq))}")` :)

Comment: @not_speshal I upvoted your comment but I won't include it in the answer. Otherwise I'd need to explain `map` and formatted strings. I'd rather keep the answer focused on loops.

Comment: @not_speshal: *Technically* that changes behavior (you remove a space after the `#`). That said, I'd typically want that space removed. And yes, I spent the whole time reading this thinking "`(func(x) for x in y)` could just be `map(func, y)`!" (I recognize that my love of `map` for the microoptimization on length and speed when you have a built-in function to use is largely irrational. No, I'll never change.)

Comment: `map` is just short and sweet :D. My preference as well!

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me

```
a = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], [2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]]

def printIntegerSequences(integerSequences):
    for i in range(len(integerSequences)):
        print("Sequence #", i+1,' '.join(str(e) for e in integerSequences[i]))

result = printIntegerSequences(a)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).